# Oracle update one of many identical rows

Tags: sql, oracle

In my DB I have identical rows. I need to update only one row.

I do it like that, but its not working.

```
update stat.stat_dial
set 
time = 200
where rownum = (select *  from  stat.stat_dial
where sesion= '0/1/0/3886.2241_D90EC01900C01899'
and rownum =1
order by time desc)
```

Comment: 2 points to note  1.  `where rownum = (select *  from  stat.stat_dial` if using where clause `select *` will not work.  2. No need of `order by` when specific mention on `ronwnum=1`

Comment: Add schema of table and required output you want.

Comment: I think you meant to use `rowid` (which is an internal "key" for a row in a table) instead of `rownum` (which is just a sequence number assigned to each row as it is returned). See @vasja's answer which looks like it will work.

Answer (score 4):

Every row should have a unique primary key  That's first normal form.

If yours doesn't, you have much bigger problems.  You should change that database ASAP.

Comment: I always say if your table doesn't have a key, you don't have data, you have junk.

Answer (score 4):

I currently can't verify this, but maybe it will work:

```
update stat.stat_dial
set time = 200
where rowid = 
    (select rowid from 
        (select rowid  from  stat.stat_dial 
                      where sesion= '0/1/0/3886.2241_D90EC01900C01899'
                         order by time desc)
        where rownum = 1 )
```

Answer (score 1):

You could update the row having the minimum rowid that meets your conditions.

```
update stat.stat_dial
set    time = 200
where  rowid = (
         select min(rowid)
         from   stat.stat_dial 
         where  sesion= '0/1/0/3886.2241_D90EC01900C01899')
```

or

```
update stat.stat_dial
set    time = 200
where  rowid = (
         select rowid
         from   stat.stat_dial 
         where  sesion= '0/1/0/3886.2241_D90EC01900C01899' and
                rownum = 1)
```

I think I prefer the latter on reflection, as the former will always return a row in the subquery even if the condition is not met, albeit with a result of NULL.

Answer (score 0):

your query is true just small problem in it, try this:

```
 update stat.stat_dial
 set 
 time = 200
 where rownum = (select rownum  from  stat.stat_dial
 where sesion= '0/1/0/3886.2241_D90EC01900C01899'
 and rownum =1
 order by time desc)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE  stat.stat_dial 
    SET   time=200
    where sesion=? and login =?
    and  rowid = (SELECT min(rowid) 
            FROM stat.stat_dial sd1
            where sd1.sesion = ? 
            or sd1.sesion= ? )
```

thats work for me. Thanks to all of you, guys.